# Should "Americana" be capitalized?

Tags: nouns, writing, capitalization

In the following sentence, should *Americana* be capitalized?

> Here's a list of great Americana books.

It looks so weird when written lowercase.

Comment: Should not it be _American_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: it could be, but Americana has a distinct meaning. [Americana](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Americana#Noun): *All things peculiar to the United States' culture and people, anything that is a symbol of American life.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjectives that derive from a proper noun are written in capital case; it is also true for nouns, even if in some cases nouns that derive from proper nouns are not written in capital case.

- *American*, from the noun *America*
- *Americana*, from the noun *America*
- *Italian*, from the noun *Italy*
- *Martian*, from the noun Mars
- *Parmesan*, from the noun *Parma*, the name of a city in Italy
- *Venusian*, from the noun *Venus*

To notice that the adjectives I reported in the list are also used as nouns.

Comment: Well, *Americana* is not an adjective, but a plural noun :)

Comment: So is _American_. **:-)**

Comment: We capitalize all words derived from nationalities and many names, but it is not true that this is done for all nouns/adjectives from proper nouns (e.g. narcissist, sodomy, atlas, echo, siren, bandaid, kleenex, aspirin, thermos, zipper, quixotic, and so on).

Comment: @kiamlaluno, *American* is both an adjective and a noun, but *Americana* is only an noun.

Comment: @FX_: I didn't say that _American_ is not a noun.

Comment: They are written in capital case if the link with the proper noun is still perceived; nowadays, probably few persons knows that echo derives from the name of the nymph. Bandaid, and kleenex derives from brand names with a trademark; the NOAD still reports Kleenex, for example. The NOAD reports that _aspirin is a synthetic compound used medicinally to relieve mild or chronic pain_ and that the alternative name is _acetylsalicylic acid_; if the noun was originally a trademarked name, then it is not perceived so, now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, similar to national adjectives, Americana should be capitalized.  Here's [a reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Americana)